# could not exec dpkg!

Tags: dpkg

everyone please i need a help here, i have been stuck with this problem for hours.

I mistakenly deleted my /usr/bin/dpkg  while trying to solve Mongodb problem  that i was facing. After deleting it i ran into this error that has kept me looking for solution for hours now.

`Could not exec dpkg!`

`E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (100)`

I literally can't do anything write now because of this error, i can't even, if i run ` sudo apt-get upgrade` the error will appear and i can't seems to find a solution to it, all the answers i saw online did not work for me. 
Please someone should help me out here.

regarding the question about the version of my Linux, here is it.

`Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan`

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.